# EclipseLink EntityManager.merge returns old data

Tags: java, jpa, merge, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

Strange behaviour, occurs only the first call of `em.merge()`; subsequent calls *seems* to work.

this is the EJB

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class PersistenceService implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersistenceService.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager()
    {
        return em;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        logger.debug("called");

        em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

        em.setProperty("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetrieveMode.USE);
        em.setProperty("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", CacheStoreMode.REFRESH);

        UnitOfWork uow = em.unwrap(UnitOfWork.class);
        uow.setShouldPerformDeletesFirst(true);
    }

    public <T extends AbstractEntity> T update(T entity)
    {
        logger.debug("em.contains(entity): {}", em.contains(entity));

        if(entity instanceof NamedEntity)
        {
            logger.debug("========================> name: {}", ((NamedEntity) entity).getName());
        }

        // em.clear();
        T entity2 = em.merge(entity);
        // em.flush();
        // em.refresh(entity2);

        if(entity instanceof NamedEntity)
        {
            logger.debug("========================> name: {}", ((NamedEntity) entity2).getName());
        }

        return entity2;
    }
}
```

and this is the output (in square brackets there are `[id@version]`):

```
Info: update[:192] - em.contains(entity): false
Info: update[:205] - ========================> name: WP 6.6 - SYSTEM SAFETY ASSESSMENT aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Info: update[:216] - ========================> name: WP 6.6 - SYSTEM SAFETY ASSESSMENT
```

I'm on GlassFish 4.1 with EclipseLink 2.6.0

the entity is read by a JSF `@ViewScoped` bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EntityBean<T extends AbstractEntity> implements Serializable
{
    @EJB
    protected PersistenceService service;

    protected T entity;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        Class<T> entityClass = ...;
        Long entityId = ...;

        entity = service.find(entityClass, entityId);
    }

    public String update()
    {
        entity = service.update(entity);

        return null;
    }

    ...
}
```

and this is the output when merge does not occur:

```
Info: i.s.edea2.jsf.controller.EntityBean.update[:116] - ========================> name: WP 6.6 - SYSTEM SAFETY ASSESSMENT ggg
Info: it.shape.edea2.ejb.PersistenceService.update[:107] - em.contains(entity): false
Info: it.shape.edea2.ejb.PersistenceService.update[:112] - ========================> name: WP 6.6 - SYSTEM SAFETY ASSESSMENT ggg
Finer: client acquired: 498718168
Finer: TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
Finer: acquire unit of work: 2093541910
Finest: Merge clone with references it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Manufacturer@3aaf83f[213@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a88239[151@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c0419[13@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03f8[5@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03fd[9@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03fb[8@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03f7[4@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a8851e[60@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03f8[5@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a8851e[60@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemType@135ab[147@10362]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.UnitRegistration@d40e7aea[69545@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Finest: Execute query ReadObjectQuery(referenceClass=Item )
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT ID, DTYPE, CODE, CUSTOMERDECISIONDATE, CUSTOMERDECISIONNOTE, CUSTOMERSTATUS, CUSTOMERSUBMITDATE, CUSTOMERSUBMITNOTE, DESCRIPTION, EXPECTEDRELEASEDATE, NAME, RELEASEDATE, REVISION, SECURITYLEVEL, STATUS, SUBSTATUS, VERSION, MANUFACTURER_ID, RESPONSIBLE_ID, UNITTYPE_ID, CREATED_ID, UPDATED_ID, ACTIVITY_ID, CATEGORY_ID, DOCUMENTATIONLEVEL_ID, GENERATOR_CHANGE_ID, CONSORTIUMPARTNUMBER, EQUIPMENTCODE, ITEM_FAMILY, NUC, OEMPARTNUMBER FROM UNIT WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (DTYPE = ?))
    bind => [69545, Item]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="manufacturer" referenceClass=Manufacturer sql="SELECT ID, CITY, CODE, EMAIL, ENABLED, NAME, NATION, STATE, STREET, URL, VERSION, ZONE FROM MANUFACTURER WHERE (ID = ?)")
FetchGroup(){code, city, nation, zone, street, name, id, state, version, email, enabled, url}
Finest: Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="responsible" referenceClass=Person sql="SELECT t0.ID, t0.DTYPE, t0.CODE, t0.NAME, t0.VERSION, t1.EMAIL, t1.FIRSTNAME, t1.LASTNAME, t1.LOCALE, t1.TIMEZONE, t1.OFFICE_ID, t1.PROFILE_ID FROM SUBJECT t0, PERSON t1 WHERE ((t0.ID = ?) AND ((t1.ID = t0.ID) AND (t0.DTYPE = ?)))")
FetchGroup(){rightSet, lastName, code, profile, timeZone, office, locale, roleList, version, subordinateOfficeList, firstName, accountList, name, takenProxyList, id, givenProxyList, teamList, email}
Finest: Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="type" referenceClass=UnitType sql="SELECT ID, DTYPE, ATTACHMENTSALLOWED, CODE, CUSTOMERPERMISSION, ENABLED, EXPECTEDRELEASEDATEPERMISSION, NAME, PROGRESSIVE, PROGRESSIVEYEAR, TYPEORDER, VERSION FROM UNIT_TYPE WHERE (ID = ?)")
FetchGroup(){code, typeOrder, customFieldDefinitionList, actionRuleList, progressiveYear, version, enabled, attachmentsAllowed, expectedReleaseDatePermission, customerPermission, name, progressive, id, documentRuleList}
Finest: Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="created" referenceClass=UnitRegistration )
Finest: Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="media" referenceClass=ArchiveMedia sql="SELECT ID, CODE, NAME, TYPE, VERSION, SHELF_ID, UNIT_ID FROM ARCHIVE_MEDIA WHERE (UNIT_ID = ?)")
FetchGroup(){unit, code, name, id, type, version, shelf}
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT ID, CODE, NAME, TYPE, VERSION, SHELF_ID, UNIT_ID FROM ARCHIVE_MEDIA WHERE (UNIT_ID = ?)
    bind => [69545]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Finest: Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="updated" referenceClass=UnitRegistration )
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.UnitRegistration@d487cc1a[202795@1]
Finest: Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="actionList" referenceClass=Action sql="SELECT t1.ID, t1.DTYPE, t1.CODE, t1.CUSTOMERDECISIONDATE, t1.CUSTOMERDECISIONNOTE, t1.CUSTOMERSTATUS, t1.CUSTOMERSUBMITDATE, t1.CUSTOMERSUBMITNOTE, t1.EXPECTEDRELEASEDATE, t1.NAME, t1.RELEASEDATE, t1.REVISION, t1.SECURITYLEVEL, t1.STATUS, t1.SUBSTATUS, t1.VERSION, t1.MANUFACTURER_ID, t1.RESPONSIBLE_ID, t1.UNITTYPE_ID, t1.CREATED_ID, t1.UPDATED_ID, t1.OPENDATE, t1.SUSPENDEDDATE, t1.PHASE_ID, t1.SEVERITY_ID FROM ACTION_RELATION t0, UNIT t1 WHERE (((t0.PARENT_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.CHILD_ID)) AND (t1.DTYPE = ?))")
FetchGroup(){code, customerSubmitDate, media, type, parentList, customerSubmitNote, manufacturer, productSet, customerStatus, securityLevel, registrationList, attachmentList, responsible, approvalList, customFieldMap, id, projectSet, phase, severity, customerDecisionDate, customerDecisionNote, releaseDate, workflowExecution, created, actionList, version, subStatus, revision, authorizationList, documentList, name, expectedReleaseDate, openDate, suspendedDate, updated, status}
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT t1.ID, t1.DTYPE, t1.CODE, t1.CUSTOMERDECISIONDATE, t1.CUSTOMERDECISIONNOTE, t1.CUSTOMERSTATUS, t1.CUSTOMERSUBMITDATE, t1.CUSTOMERSUBMITNOTE, t1.EXPECTEDRELEASEDATE, t1.NAME, t1.RELEASEDATE, t1.REVISION, t1.SECURITYLEVEL, t1.STATUS, t1.SUBSTATUS, t1.VERSION, t1.MANUFACTURER_ID, t1.RESPONSIBLE_ID, t1.UNITTYPE_ID, t1.CREATED_ID, t1.UPDATED_ID, t1.OPENDATE, t1.SUSPENDEDDATE, t1.PHASE_ID, t1.SEVERITY_ID FROM ACTION_RELATION t0, UNIT t1 WHERE (((t0.PARENT_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.CHILD_ID)) AND (t1.DTYPE = ?))
    bind => [69545, Action]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="baselineList" referenceClass=Baseline sql="SELECT t1.ID, t1.CODE, t1.NAME, t1.REVISION, t1.TYPE, t1.VERSION, t1.PROJECT_ID, t1.ROOT_ID FROM BASELINE_DELIVERABLE t0, BASELINE t1 WHERE ((t0.DELIVERABLE_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.BASELINE_ID))")
FetchGroup(){code, root, deliverableList, name, project, id, type, version, revision}
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT t1.ID, t1.CODE, t1.NAME, t1.REVISION, t1.TYPE, t1.VERSION, t1.PROJECT_ID, t1.ROOT_ID FROM BASELINE_DELIVERABLE t0, BASELINE t1 WHERE ((t0.DELIVERABLE_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.BASELINE_ID))
    bind => [69545]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="documentList" referenceClass=Document sql="SELECT t1.ID, t1.DTYPE, t1.CODE, t1.CUSTOMERDECISIONDATE, t1.CUSTOMERDECISIONNOTE, t1.CUSTOMERSTATUS, t1.CUSTOMERSUBMITDATE, t1.CUSTOMERSUBMITNOTE, t1.EXPECTEDRELEASEDATE, t1.NAME, t1.RELEASEDATE, t1.REVISION, t1.SECURITYLEVEL, t1.STATUS, t1.SUBSTATUS, t1.VERSION, t1.MANUFACTURER_ID, t1.RESPONSIBLE_ID, t1.UNITTYPE_ID, t1.CREATED_ID, t1.UPDATED_ID, t1.ACTIVITY_ID, t1.CATEGORY_ID, t1.DOCUMENTATIONLEVEL_ID, t1.GENERATOR_CHANGE_ID, t1.DOCUMENT_FAMILY FROM DOCUMENT_RELATION t0, UNIT t1 WHERE (((t0.PARENT_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.CHILD_ID)) AND (t1.DTYPE = ?))")
FetchGroup(){code, activity, customerSubmitDate, changeList, media, type, parentList, customerSubmitNote, manufacturer, productSet, customerStatus, securityLevel, registrationList, attachmentList, responsible, approvalList, customFieldMap, id, projectSet, generatorChange, lifecycleAssociationList, remarkList, customerDecisionDate, customerDecisionNote, releaseDate, workflowExecution, created, documentationLevel, actionList, version, subStatus, revision, authorizationList, documentList, name, expectedReleaseDate, family, category, updated, status, baselineList}
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT t1.ID, t1.DTYPE, t1.CODE, t1.CUSTOMERDECISIONDATE, t1.CUSTOMERDECISIONNOTE, t1.CUSTOMERSTATUS, t1.CUSTOMERSUBMITDATE, t1.CUSTOMERSUBMITNOTE, t1.EXPECTEDRELEASEDATE, t1.NAME, t1.RELEASEDATE, t1.REVISION, t1.SECURITYLEVEL, t1.STATUS, t1.SUBSTATUS, t1.VERSION, t1.MANUFACTURER_ID, t1.RESPONSIBLE_ID, t1.UNITTYPE_ID, t1.CREATED_ID, t1.UPDATED_ID, t1.ACTIVITY_ID, t1.CATEGORY_ID, t1.DOCUMENTATIONLEVEL_ID, t1.GENERATOR_CHANGE_ID, t1.DOCUMENT_FAMILY FROM DOCUMENT_RELATION t0, UNIT t1 WHERE (((t0.PARENT_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.CHILD_ID)) AND (t1.DTYPE = ?))
    bind => [69545, Document]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="productSet" referenceClass=Product sql="SELECT t1.ID, t1.CODE, t1.ENDDATE, t1.LASTASSIGNEDCODE, t1.NAME, t1.STARTDATE, t1.VERSION, t1.RESPONSIBLE_ID, t1.ROOT_ID FROM PRODUCT_UNIT t0, PRODUCT t1 WHERE ((t0.UNIT_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.PRODUCT_ID))")
FetchGroup(){code, lastAssignedCode, endDate, responsible, root, name, unitList, id, version, startDate, operativeList}
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT t1.ID, t1.CODE, t1.ENDDATE, t1.LASTASSIGNEDCODE, t1.NAME, t1.STARTDATE, t1.VERSION, t1.RESPONSIBLE_ID, t1.ROOT_ID FROM PRODUCT_UNIT t0, PRODUCT t1 WHERE ((t0.UNIT_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.PRODUCT_ID))
    bind => [69545]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="projectSet" referenceClass=Project sql="SELECT t1.ID, t1.CODE, t1.ENDDATE, t1.LASTASSIGNEDCODE, t1.NAME, t1.STARTDATE, t1.VERSION, t1.RESPONSIBLE_ID, t1.ROOT_ID, t1.TYPE_ID FROM PROJECT_UNIT t0, PROJECT t1 WHERE ((t0.UNIT_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.PROJECT_ID))")
FetchGroup(){code, lastAssignedCode, endDate, assuranceOutputList, unitList, type, version, responsible, root, name, id, startDate, lifecycleAssociationList, operativeList, baselineList}
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT t1.ID, t1.CODE, t1.ENDDATE, t1.LASTASSIGNEDCODE, t1.NAME, t1.STARTDATE, t1.VERSION, t1.RESPONSIBLE_ID, t1.ROOT_ID, t1.TYPE_ID FROM PROJECT_UNIT t0, PROJECT t1 WHERE ((t0.UNIT_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.PROJECT_ID))
    bind => [69545]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Project@26e0957c[254@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@92af664e[2@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@620[1@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@7a006f21[16094@2]{A1000|PI060060-09|}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Manufacturer@3aaf83f[213@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@92af664e[2@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemType@1059c[128@271]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.UnitRegistration@34cb396d[16094@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a88160[173@5]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c041b[15@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03f8[5@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@7a006f21[16094@2]{A1000|PI060060-09|}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ProjectType@923007ea[13@117]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ProtoDeliverable@92300b8c[3@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemType@1059c[128@271]
Finest: Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="remarkList" referenceClass=Remark sql="SELECT t1.ID, t1.CODE, t1.NAME, t1.SECURITYLEVEL, t1.TYPE, t1.VERSION, t1.RESPONSIBLE_ID, t1.SEVERITY_ID FROM DELIVERABLE_REMARK t0, REMARK t1 WHERE ((t0.DELIVERABLE_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.REMARK_ID))")
FetchGroup(){securityLevel, severity, authorizationList, code, attachmentList, reworkList, responsible, deliverableList, name, id, type, version}
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT t1.ID, t1.CODE, t1.NAME, t1.SECURITYLEVEL, t1.TYPE, t1.VERSION, t1.RESPONSIBLE_ID, t1.SEVERITY_ID FROM DELIVERABLE_REMARK t0, REMARK t1 WHERE ((t0.DELIVERABLE_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.REMARK_ID))
    bind => [69545]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="childItemList" referenceClass=ItemRelation sql="SELECT ID, IOR, QUANTITY, VERSION, CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID FROM ITEM_RELATION WHERE (PARENT_ID = ?)")
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT ID, IOR, QUANTITY, VERSION, CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID FROM ITEM_RELATION WHERE (PARENT_ID = ?)
    bind => [69545]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="lifecycleAssociationList" referenceClass=LifecycleAssociation sql="SELECT ID, EXPECTEDDELIVERYDATE, MANDATORY, ASSOCIATION_MODE, PHASE, VERSION, DELIVERABLE_ID, PROJECT_ID FROM LIFECYCLE_ASSOCIATION WHERE (DELIVERABLE_ID = ?)")
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT ID, EXPECTEDDELIVERYDATE, MANDATORY, ASSOCIATION_MODE, PHASE, VERSION, DELIVERABLE_ID, PROJECT_ID FROM LIFECYCLE_ASSOCIATION WHERE (DELIVERABLE_ID = ?)
    bind => [69545]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="parentItemList" referenceClass=ItemRelation sql="SELECT ID, IOR, QUANTITY, VERSION, CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID FROM ITEM_RELATION WHERE (CHILD_ID = ?)")
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT ID, IOR, QUANTITY, VERSION, CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID FROM ITEM_RELATION WHERE (CHILD_ID = ?)
    bind => [69545]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemRelation@47f45362[6024@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@b490b8d5[16119@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80|}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Manufacturer@3aaf83f[213@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a88239[151@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemType@135a6[146@2524]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.UnitRegistration@25f5fb38[16119@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a885d9[162@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c0419[13@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@b490b8d5[16119@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80|}
Finest: Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="authorizationList" referenceClass=Authorization sql="SELECT ID, INTERVENTION, VERSION, SUBJECT_ID, ELEMENT_ORDER FROM AUTHORIZATION WHERE (UNIT_ID = ?)")
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: SELECT ID, INTERVENTION, VERSION, SUBJECT_ID, ELEMENT_ORDER FROM AUTHORIZATION WHERE (UNIT_ID = ?)
    bind => [69545]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [read].
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Authorization@e0a88258[23960@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a88239[151@2]
Info: it.shape.edea2.ejb.PersistenceService.update[:134] - ========================> name: WP 6.6 - SYSTEM SAFETY ASSESSMENT
Finer: TX beforeCompletion callback, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
Finer: begin unit of work commit
Finer: TX beginTransaction, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
Finest: Execute query UpdateObjectQuery(it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemType@135ab[147@10362])
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: UPDATE UNIT_TYPE SET VERSION = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (VERSION = ?))
    bind => [10363, 147, 10362]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [default].
Finer: TX afterCompletion callback, status=COMMITTED
Finer: end unit of work commit
Finer: release unit of work
Finer: client released
Info: i.s.edea2.jsf.controller.EntityBean.setEntity[:211] - entity: it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Info: i.s.edea2.jsf.controller.EntityBean.update[:127] - ========================> name: WP 6.6 - SYSTEM SAFETY ASSESSMENT
```

and this is the output of the secon try, when merge occurs:

```
Info: i.s.edea2.jsf.controller.EntityBean.update[:116] - ========================> name: WP 6.6 - SYSTEM SAFETY ASSESSMENT hhh
Info: it.shape.edea2.ejb.PersistenceService.update[:107] - em.contains(entity): false
Info: it.shape.edea2.ejb.PersistenceService.update[:112] - ========================> name: WP 6.6 - SYSTEM SAFETY ASSESSMENT hhh
Finer: client acquired: 1596825453
Finer: TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
Finer: acquire unit of work: 16368269
Finest: Merge clone with references it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Manufacturer@3aaf83f[213@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a88239[151@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c0419[13@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03f8[5@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03fd[9@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03fb[8@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03f7[4@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a8851e[60@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03f8[5@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a8851e[60@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemType@135ab[147@10363]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.UnitRegistration@d40e7aea[69545@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.UnitRegistration@d487cc1a[202795@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Project@26e0957c[254@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@92af664e[2@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@620[1@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@7a006f21[16094@2]{A1000|PI060060-09|}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Manufacturer@3aaf83f[213@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@92af664e[2@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemType@1059c[128@271]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.UnitRegistration@34cb396d[16094@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a88160[173@5]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c041b[15@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c03f8[5@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@7a006f21[16094@2]{A1000|PI060060-09|}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ProjectType@923007ea[13@117]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ProtoDeliverable@92300b8c[3@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemType@1059c[128@271]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemRelation@47f45362[6024@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@b490b8d5[16119@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80|}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Manufacturer@3aaf83f[213@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a88239[151@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemType@135a6[146@2524]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.UnitRegistration@25f5fb38[16119@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a885d9[162@2]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Office@184c0419[13@3]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@b490b8d5[16119@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80|}
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Authorization@e0a88258[23960@1]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Person@e0a88239[151@2]
Info: it.shape.edea2.ejb.PersistenceService.update[:134] - ========================> name: WP 6.6 - SYSTEM SAFETY ASSESSMENT hhh
Finer: TX beforeCompletion callback, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
Finer: begin unit of work commit
Finer: TX beginTransaction, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
Finest: Execute query UpdateObjectQuery(it.shape.edea2.jpa.ItemType@135ab[147@10363])
Finest: Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
Finest: reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine: UPDATE UNIT_TYPE SET VERSION = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (VERSION = ?))
    bind => [10364, 147, 10363]
Finest: Execute query UpdateObjectQuery(it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6})
Info: i.s.edea2.ejb.listener.UnitListener.preUpdateWithChanges[:55] - entity: it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Finest: Execute query InsertObjectQuery(it.shape.edea2.jpa.UnitRegistration@c1326ae5[null@null])
Fine: INSERT INTO UNIT_REGISTRATION (REG_DATE, VERSION, PERSON_ID, UNIT_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [2015-05-21 18:24:58.099, 1, 2, 69545]
Finest: Execute query ValueReadQuery(name="GLOBAL_SEQUENCE" sql="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
Fine: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
Finest: assign sequence to the object (207.728 -> it.shape.edea2.jpa.UnitRegistration@c1326ae5[null@1])
Finest: Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="registrationList" referenceClass=UnitRegistration sql="SELECT ID, REG_DATE, VERSION, PERSON_ID, UNIT_ID FROM UNIT_REGISTRATION WHERE (UNIT_ID = ?)")
Fine: SELECT ID, REG_DATE, VERSION, PERSON_ID, UNIT_ID FROM UNIT_REGISTRATION WHERE (UNIT_ID = ?)
    bind => [69545]
Finest: Register the existing object it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@3]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Fine: UPDATE UNIT SET NAME = ?, UPDATED_ID = ?, VERSION = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (VERSION = ?))
    bind => [WP 6.6 - SYSTEM SAFETY ASSESSMENT hhh, 207728, 4, 69545, 3]
Finest: Connection released to connection pool [default].
Finer: TX afterCompletion callback, status=COMMITTED
Finer: end unit of work commit
Finer: release unit of work
Finer: client released
Info: i.s.edea2.jsf.controller.EntityBean.setEntity[:211] - entity: it.shape.edea2.jpa.Item@6a6dedd6[69545@4]{A1000|PI060060-09.80.60|WP 6.6}
Info: i.s.edea2.jsf.controller.EntityBean.update[:127] - ========================> name: WP 6.6 - SYSTEM SAFETY ASSESSMENT hhh
```

and this is the persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="edea2" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/edea2</jta-data-source>

        <class>it.shape.core.jpa.AbstractEntity</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="${edea2.jdbc.driverClass}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${edea2.jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${edea2.jdbc.user}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${edea2.jdbc.password}" />

            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="${edea2.eclipselink.targetDatabase}" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.index-foreign-keys" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm really out of ideas...

Comment: What are the values in entity after the merge?  How was entity intially read in, and does removing the javax.persistence.cache.storeMode refresh option affect anything?  Try turning on logging to see what might be causing the refresh and when exactly it is occuring

Comment: @Chris please see the update with full logs. Removing cache properties does not affect.

Comment: another info: disabling cache via `<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>` makes EntityManager **always** return old entity after merge. Seems like a BIG cache issue...

Comment: Where is the entity you are passing into merge coming from, how was it read in?  I suspect it was read in using a refresh option,and some lazy attribute is getting triggered on merge forcing the overwrite.

Comment: The entity comes from JSF @ViewScoped bean and it is read in the same bean (previous request) with the same EJB. No refresh is used (nor hint nor em.refresh). When i try to em.refresh in other situations, often I get the infamous "is not from this UnitOfWork object space, but the parent session's"